# kubernetes ingress certificate

Tags: kubernetes, certificate, kubernetes-ingress

unable to create kubernetes tls secret.

Generated Standard SSL from GoDaddy, downloaded key csr and crt:
generated-private.key , generated.csr and e3d279cb54c1cdc7.crt

kubectl create secret tls production-tls --key generated-private.key --cert e3d279cb54c1cdc7.crt

error:
"failed to load key pair tls: failed to find any PEM data in key input"

private key content (generated-private.key)

-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEvgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKgwggSkAgEAAoIBAQChdTdnfDP2jDiw
TjfjxR3J4NS4VOBldm4A2uHbmftkt9OoqvQc4yhHAQIw6VD3PnwrzbP+sAeSUCj7
...........
S5rcQ7YLOkcKxqUAL85Q8NoT
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----

I am lost here any input will be helpful

Thanks,

Comment: Like the errors message says, there is PEM missing. Meaning you need to generate  `PEM` file from your cert files and attache it instead.

Comment: trying to convert to pem returns : unable to load private key
140073253767032:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:708:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY

Comment: What exactly are you doing to conver it?